# Alfresco - advanced search gives 0 results when using the wildcard(*) with the text value

Tags: solr, wildcard, alfresco, solr6, alfresco-enterprise

For custom document type when I use advanced search for searching the particular documents that have same custom property, with writing complete property value in advanced search gives expected result(list of documents that have the same property) but when I am using the wildcard(*) with the property value, advanced search gives 0 results for the same property that I mentioned just above. This only happens to only one property value.

For example,

- propertyName = Package Name
- propertyType = text

In the metadata field when I type,

- case 1 (enter complete name) : 10.1234/abc/10.abc

  output: 10 documents
- case 2 (enter value + wildcard) : 10.1234*

  output: 0 document
- case 3 (enter value + wildcard) : 10.1234/a*

  output: 10 documents

suppose, search with other values for different documents

In the metadata field when I type,

- case 1 (enter complete name) : 10.4444/xyz/10.xyz

  output: 5 documents
- case 2 (enter value + wildcard) : 10.444*

  output: 5 document
- case 3 (enter value + wildcard) : 10.4444/x*

  output: 5 documents

This issue I confirmed by using the Node Browser (available in Admin Tools) for searching the documents

The possible solution I did was to reindex the Solr but the issue persists.

Version information:

- Alfresco(Enterprise) - 5.2.1
- Solr - 6
- Alfresco search service - 1.3.2

Comment: if the metadata is of the type string or its non tokenized then the behavior correct and expected. The wildcard works if the field is non tokenized or the field is of type string.

Comment: The value is of type text and non-tokenized. The wildcard is working for all values except one value.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of your field in the schema.xml and if it is string, then **change string type to text_general** and use the df = *text* for search. That might work.